# How to automate application deployment when using LXD containers?

Tags: lxc, lxd

How should applications be scripted/automatically deployed when in LXD containers?

For example is best way to deploy applications in LXD containers to use a bash script (which deploys an application)? How to execute this bash script inside the container by executing a command on the host?

Are there any tools/methods of doing this in a similar way to Docker recipes?

Comment: Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/617865/is-there-a-way-to-configure-lxd-containers-with-cloud-config-at-provision-time, you can also use .sh files instead of .yml for cloud init files, note that cloud-init is only available for ubuntu: release images not the images: remote. you could also use exec from the host `lxc exec my-container -- bash -c "top -n 1 -b"`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to execute the deployment script on the host. We have the LXD client installed on our continuous integration environment, with the production/staging hosts added as remote servers. This way you can execute lxd commands and push files directly to remote containers from a build environment, rather than connecting to an LXD host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I use Ansible to:

1. build the LXD containers (web, database, redis for example).
2. connect to the containers and deploy the services and code needed.

you can build your own images for example with the services and/or code already deployed and build specific containers from this images.

I was doing this from before LXD had Ansible support (Ansible 2.2) i prefer to use ssh instead of lxd connection, when i connect to the containers to deploy services/code. they comes with a profile where i had setup my ssh public key (to have direct ssh connection by keys ... no passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my open source project on bitbucket [devops_lxd_containers](https://bitbucket.org/joexdobs/devops_lxd_containers/src/master/) It includes:

- Scripts to build lxd image templates including Apache, tomcat, haproxy.
- Scripts to demonstrate custom application image builds such as Apache hosting and key/value content and haproxy configured as a router.
- Code to launch the containers and map ports so they are accessible to the larger network
- Code to configure haproxy as layer 7 proxy to route http requests between boxes and containers based on uri prefix routing.  Based on where it previously deployed and mapped ports.
- At the higher level it accepts a data drive spec and will deploy an entire environment compose of many containers spread across many hosts and hook them all up to act as a cohesive whole via a layer 7 proxy.
- Extensive documentation showing [how I accomplished each major step](https://bitbucket.org/joexdobs/devops_lxd_containers/src/master/documentation/devops-with-lxd.md) using code snippets before automating.
- Code to support zero-outage upgrades using the layer7 ability to gracefully bleed off old connections while accepting new connections at the new layer.

The entire system is built on the premise that image building is best done in layers.  We build a updated Ubuntu image.  From it we build a hardened Ubuntu image.  From it we build a basic Apache image.   From it we build an application specific image like our apacheKV sample.   The goal is to never rebuild any more than once and to re-use the common functionality such as the basicJDK as the source for all JDK dependent images so we can avoid having duplicate code in any location.   I have strived to keep Image or template creation completely separate from deployment and port mapping. The exception is that I could not complete creation of the layer 7 routing image until we knew everything about how other images would be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Hashicorp Packer with the [`ansible` provisioner](https://www.packer.io/plugins/provisioners/ansible/ansible) using `ansible_connection = lxd`

- Some notes here for [constructing a template](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-ansible/issues/95#issuecomment-1086929446)
- When iterating through `local` files on your host system you **may** need to be using `ansible_connection = local` (e.g for `stat` & friends)
- Using `local_action` in ansible with the `lxd` connection is still
  action inside the container when using `stat` (but not with `include_vars` & `lookup` function for files)
- Using lots of `debug` messages in Ansible is helpful to know which `local` environment ansible is actually operating in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one here mentioned Canonicals own tool for managing LXD.

https://juju.is

it is super simple, well supported, and the only caveat is it requires you turn off ipv6 at the LXD/LXC side of things (in the network bridge)

```
snap install juju --classic
juju bootstrap localhost
```

from there you can learn about juju models, deploy machines or prebaked images like ubuntuOS

```
juju deploy ubuntu
```